How to have error handling in applab code.org
I want to make a signup/login page but i want it to check if the data table of the username excists to then make an data table for all the data attributed to that user.
I think the only way to do this is throught error handling and if anyone knows how then please tell me.
I expected a way to code error handling and looking at all the data tables

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
